# Write a function that returns true for regular expressions that match the empty string in Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is the code:

```
import Data.List
data RE sym
    = Never             -- match no strings
    | Empty             -- match empty string
    | Symbol sym        -- match singleton string
    | RE sym :+ RE sym  -- choice
    | RE sym :* RE sym  -- concatenation
    | Repeat (RE sym)   -- repeat zero or more times
    | Plus (RE sym)     -- repeat one or more times
    deriving (Show, Eq)

infixr 6 :+, .+.
infixr 7 :*, .*.

data ABC = A | B | C deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

Write a function matchEmpty that returns true for regular expressions that match the empty string.

```
matchEmpty :: RE sym -> Bool
matchEmpty = ???
```

This is What I write:

```
matchEmpty (Empty :+ _) = True
matchEmpty Empty = True
matchEmpty Never = False
matchEmpty (_) = False
matchEmpty(Repeat(_)) = True
```

but i still got error for some cases:

```
Testing matchEmpty
INCORRECT: A*
       wanted: True
       got:    False

INCORRECT: (A|e)+
       wanted: True
       got:    False

INCORRECT: (AB)*
       wanted: True
       got:    False
```

I am so lost for this one, Please help me to do this one,  I am a beginner in Haskell and try to learn it by myself. 
Does there need recursion or something else to do this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problems you have are that:

1. `Repeat (Symbol A)` is incorrectly marked false.

   This is because patterns are matched from top to bottom, so `matchEmpty (_) = False` catches it instead of `matchEmpty(Repeat(_)) = True`
2. `Plus (x)` is incorrectly always marked as false.

   This should be true when `x` matches the empty string (yes, this would be a recursive check).
3. `x :- y` is correctly marked as true when `x` is `Empty`, but incorrectly fails these cases:

   `Symbol A :+ Empty` -- the other side is empty

   `(Repeat _) :+ (Empty :+ Empty)` -- neither side is `Empty` itself, but still matches the empty string (this would also be a recursive check)
4. `x :* y` is always incorrectly marked false. This should be true when *both* sides can match the empty string (also recursive).

You can give it another go now with those observations.

For a spoiler, here's my suggestion:

```
matchEmpty Empty = True
matchEmpty (Repeat _) = True
matchEmpty (Plus x) = matchEmpty x
matchEmpty (x :+ y) = matchEmpty x || matchEmpty y
matchEmpty (x :* y) = matchEmpty x && matchEmpty y
matchEmpty _ = False
```

Comment: Thank you anyway..... I tried ur suggestion and i got more error.......

Comment: It works with the cases you mentioned in the post. Which new cases failed?

Comment: Testing matchEmpty
INCORRECT: e|A
       wanted: True
       got:    False

INCORRECT: A*
       wanted: True
       got:    False

INCORRECT: (A|e)+
       wanted: True
       got:    False

INCORRECT: (AB)*
       wanted: True
       got:    False

INCORRECT: eA*
       wanted: True
       got:    False

Comment: It works for all these cases when I try them manually. Are you sure you completely deleted all traces of your old `matchEmpty` function? Are you sure the file is saved and recompiled?

Comment: It was my fault, I added more parentheses just now , it works now, Thank you!